# js: jasny's upload widget in a flask project

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Have a flask project where I'd like to replace a standard file upload form with something a little bit nicer:

```
<form action="" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type=file name=file>
    <input type=submit value=Upload>
</form>
```

Have been looking into using [jasny's bootstrap upload widget](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload), but, after loading the correct `.js` and `.css` files and incorporating the following HTML

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
  <div class="input-append">
    <div class="uneditable-input span3">
      <i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i>
      <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
    </div>
    <span class="btn btn-file">
      <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
      <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
      <input type="file" />
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how to set up the event to actually upload the file in question. I'm guessing that I hook a different button up to a submit event, but I'm not certain what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that plugin works by binding events to existing DOM objects. Did you call

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload()
```

after the DOM was ready? If you called it before the element was added to the DOM, it wouldn't find any element to bind events to.

Comment: okay, so all I should need to do in theory afterwards is to add an upload button with a "fileupload" class in the same div?

Comment: The outermost div already has the "fileupload" class, it just doesn't have any behavior until `$.fileupload()` gets called on it.